# How can I use netsh to find a rule using a pattern

Tags: find, windows-firewall, netsh

I'm wondering whether anyone in Microsoft has ever come to a situation where they can't remember a rule's name!
The `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule` only accepts **1** name and no pattern matching facility is available on netsh to help find a rule using a pattern like `"SQL*"` or `^SQL.+$`
using show and `name=all` it is possible to list all rules but I was unable to find a solid command-line grep tool for windows.

I want to be able to run a command like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=sql*
```

Is this possible?

Comment: a fast answer would be: `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "SQL"`; but the output and the control is not as satisfying as it should be. It's rather messy and even worse, Case-Sensitive ...

Comment: think the following link may help   http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/02/18/how-to-manage-the-windows-firewall-settings-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Using Powershell is another option; yes. but what if you want to do this on a remote machine? Is it possible to leave the remote ports for PS open and have IDS/IPS like what I have with BvSsshServer? I'm looking for something available in Windows' native command prompt.

Comment: It seems like it's possible to secure PS using SSL: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Comment: I've found that using `/I` with `FIND` command, I can dodge the case-sensitive problem; but the result is still messy...

Comment: The GNUWin32 project has a nice `grep` for windows...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In PowerShell run:

```
$fw=New-object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2    
$fw.rules | findstr /i "whaturlookingfor"
```

better yet:

```
$fw.rules | select name | select-string "sql"
```

Comment: $fw.rules | where-object {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.Direction -eq 1}  Helped me arrive at this (inbound enabled).

Comment: further, you can select only certain properties of the rule.  `$fw.Rules | where-object {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.Direction -eq 1} |  Select-Object -property name, direction, enabled`

Comment: I'm confused, is this meant to be run in a netsh prompt? Or some other environment?

Comment: This has to be run in a PowerShell prompt or as part of a PowerShell (.ps1) script. `New-Object` is a PowerShell cmdlet that provides access to the much older COM API while preserving PowerShell syntax and object structure.

Answer (score 7):

This is best I could do. Anyone know how to take it further? Like remove/subtract the Rule Name from the results?

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "Rule Name:" | find "NameLookingFor"
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10 I get a warning when I execute `netsh advfirewall`, saying that future Windows versions may not support that feature anymore and one should use PowerShell instead. Luckily, what the OP wanted to do is easy in PowerShell:

`Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQL*"`

I had 1000+ firewall rules that were created by a randomly-named executable that I wanted to remove. The following command made this easy to do:

`Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "*mongod.exe"`

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Select-String](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | select-string -pattern "Hyper-V"
```

Comment: Please don't downvote without checking that you are in the required conditions for this solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

Without PowerShell you can simply use regex with findstr:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | findstr /R "sql.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly a coat-tails answer but a comment would obscure the point.

This is also admittedly answering a slightly different question: how can I *not* use `netsh` and still find rules? :-)

I think it's best to stay in the PowerShell idiom if you're there already, and you can use the [full pattern matching capability](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx) including regexes therein.

For the sake of it, I included some conditionals and mutation to show how all PowerShell constructs are embeddable in the functional-style blocks.

Final caveat that mutations must be run with Administrative rights where as reads need not.

```
(New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^SQL.+$' } |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Output "Checking $($_.Name)"
      if ( $_.Enabled ) { Write-Output "$($_.Name) already enabled" }
      else { Write-Output "$($_.Name) enabled"; $_.Enabled = $true }
    }
```